# Custom Dummy Coding in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dummy-variable

I have a dataframe with event data. I have two columns: Primary and Secondary. The Primary and Secondary columns both contain lists of tags (e.g., ['Fun event', 'Dance party']).

```
      primary               secondary                      combined
['booze', 'party']    ['singing', 'dance']    ['booze', 'party', 'singing', 'dance']
    ['concert']        ['booze', 'vocals']     ['concert', 'booze', 'vocals']
```

I want to dummy code the data so that primary columns have a 1 code, non-observed columns have a 0, and values in the secondary column have a .5 value. Like so:

```
combined                                 booze        party   singing    dance    concert    vocals
['booze', 'party', 'singing', 'dance']     1            1       .5        .5        0           0
['concert', 'booze', 'vocals']            .5            0        0         0        1          .5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1=pd.get_dummies(df.combined.apply(pd.Series).stack()).sum(level=0)
df1[df1.apply(lambda x : [x.name in y for y in df.iloc[x.index,2]])]-=0.5

df1
Out[173]: 
   booze  concert  dance  party  singing  vocals
0    1.0        0    0.5      1      0.5     0.0
1    0.5        1    0.0      0      0.0     0.5
```

Datainput :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'primary':   [['booze', 'party'] ,  ['concert']],
                   'secondary':   [['singing', 'dance'], ['booze', 'vocals']],
                   'combined': [['booze', 'party', 'singing', 'dance'],   ['concert', 'booze', 'vocals']]})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach that works by transforming the `primary` and `secondary` columns' values into columns on the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'primary': [['booze', 'party'], ['concert']],
        'secondary': [['singing', 'dance'], ['booze', 'vocals']],
    })

# create primary and secondary indicator columns
iprim = df.primary.apply(lambda v: pd.Series([1] * len(v), index=v))
isec = df.secondary.apply(lambda v: pd.Series([.5] * len(v), index=v))

# join with primary, then update from secondary columns
df = df.join(iprim).join(isec, rsuffix='_')
df.drop([c for c in df.columns if c.endswith('_')], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.update(isec)
df.fillna(0)
```

=>

```
    primary        secondary        booze   concert     party      dance    singing     vocals
0   [booze, party] [singing, dance] 1.0     0.0         1.0         0.5         0.5     0.0
1   [concert]      [booze, vocals]  0.5     1.0         0.0         0.0         0.0     0.5
```

Note the second `.join()` uses rsuffix to add columns that were already in `primary`, whereas `.update()` is used to overwrite values in the primary columns. `.drop()` removes these columns. Rearrange to prefer primary over secondary.